# numpy _multiarray_umath.py source code shows empty functions

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to create a continuous function similar to numpy.cos(). 
But when I opened up the numpy\core_multiarray_umath.py, all of its functions only have the function name and a pass, there is no actual codes for each function, how does numpy actually work in this way:

example:

Below is the actual cos function from numpy

```
 def cos(x, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; NOTE: unreliably restored from __doc__ 
"""
cos(x, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])    
Cosine element-wise.    
Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    Input array in radians.
out : ndarray, None, or tuple of ndarray and None, optional
    A location into which the result is stored. If provided, it must have
    a shape that the inputs broadcast to. If not provided or `None`,
    a freshly-allocated array is returned. A tuple (possible only as a
    keyword argument) must have length equal to the number of outputs.
where : array_like, optional
    Values of True indicate to calculate the ufunc at that position, values
    of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone.
**kwargs
    For other keyword-only arguments, see the
    :ref:`ufunc docs <ufuncs.kwargs>`.

Returns
-------
y : ndarray
    The corresponding cosine values.
    This is a scalar if `x` is a scalar.

Notes
-----
If `out` is provided, the function writes the result into it,
and returns a reference to `out`.  (See Examples)

References
----------
M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions.
New York, NY: Dover, 1972.

Examples
--------
>>> np.cos(np.array([0, np.pi/2, np.pi]))
array([  1.00000000e+00,   6.12303177e-17,  -1.00000000e+00])
>>>
>>> # Example of providing the optional output parameter
>>> out2 = np.cos([0.1], out1)
>>> out2 is out1
True
>>>
>>> # Example of ValueError due to provision of shape mis-matched `out`
>>> np.cos(np.zeros((3,3)),np.zeros((2,2)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid return array shape
"""
pass
```

'''

Comment: The real work is compiled code. I imagine there's a general part that handles iteration, and specific part that does `cos` for each element.  Unless you know `c` well don't expect to reverse engineer this.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but this may be to help some documentation tools. For example, such a tool may not want to actually import 3rd party modules for security or performance reasons and instead rely on extracting docstrings from the python source.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html talks about making a `ufunc` using the `numpy` c-api.

Comment: … numpy\\core\\_multiarray_umath.cp36-win_amd64.pyd … from the header in multiarray.py … "In v1.16 the multiarray and umath c-extension modules were merged into a single _multiarray_umath extension module.

Comment: What functionality do you want?  Similar speed on a basic array, or all the `ufunc` bells and whistles?  There are compilation tools like `numba` if you just want speed.  If you want to experiment with `ufunc` abilities (but not the speed) consider using `np.frompyfunc`.